# Spring LDAP JPA - Limit number of result

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-ldap

I'm using **spring-ldap 2.0.4** and **spring-data-jpa 1.9.0**.
I built a JPA repository like this :

```
public interface PersonRepo extends LdapRepository<Person> {

  Person findByUid (String uid);

  @Query("(&(attribute=*{0}*)(attribute2=X)(attribute3=Y))")
  List<Person> findByAttributeContains(String attribute);
}
```

So far everything is fine. I could write methods that fill my needs thanks to query methods. 
For some queries i had to use @Query annotation because they were many **and** operator.

But i would like to **limit the number** of result to return from my second query method.

I know there is there is the **Top** and **First** keywords to define query methods in spring JPA. But I didn't manage to get it work. Plus I want to use multiple **and** operator in the method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to limit the number of result using XML LDAP configuration.

```
<ldap:ldap-template context-source-ref="contextSource" count-limit="100"/>
```